How can I have a ConstraintLayout Flow widget wrap the "containing" views and the views also take up the remaining space?
I'm trying to use a Flow widget to replace a vertical orientation LinearLayout that I was just using inside of my ConstraintLayout. It needs to satisfy all of the following:

The "containing" Flow widget must wrap the controls so that the widest view dictates the size of the flow layout.
However, the Flow widget cannot be larger than 90% of the parent (and its "containing" views must be smaller than it, respecting Flow widget padding).
The views "inside" must wrap their own contents without a hard coded width.
The views "inside" of the Flow widget must fill the empty space if they are less wide than the widest view (respecting the Flow widget padding).

If I were to express in pseudo code I'd say:

flow_widget.width = longest_child.width
contained_view.width = min( contained_view.contents.width, flow_widget.width )

Can this be done with a Flow widget and how?
My attempt:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".TestFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/centerControls"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView,editText,button"
        app:flow_verticalGap="5dp"
        app:flow_wrapMode="none"
        
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        
        app:layout_constrainedWidth_max="wrap"

        android:background="@color/green"
        
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am a text view"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am an edit view"
        android:hint="I am a hint"
        />
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am a button"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Note that in the image below the Flow widget will respect the 90% constraint but will not wrap the views.


If trying to wrap items then https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout offers a lot more control

If you want the widest view dictates the size of the flow layout,You need to set at least one view width as the maximum,And set the other view width as 0dp.
And you need to set the Flow widget width as "wrap_content".
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/centerControls"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView,editText,button"
        app:flow_verticalGap="5dp"
        app:flow_wrapMode="none"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"

        app:layout_constrainedWidth_max="wrap"

        android:background="@color/green"

        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
        tools:ignore="MissingClass" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am a text view"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am an edit view"
        android:hint="I am a hint"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am a button"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


Thank you for this. So it's not possible that it would set it on its own based on the the widths of the views? For example, if the TextView is wrapped and it is the longest based on that view? At least one of the views must be hardcoded?

That's possible.Set the base view width as “wrap_content”，The others are set to 0dp.

In your example, the first TextView still has a static width, which I'm trying to avoid. Updated my question to be hopefully more clear. Apologies for being unclear.

In my understanding, either the width of the Flow is determined, or you know which View is the widest, if all rely on adaptive, and all views are set to the widest width, I'm afraid you need to implement in code.
